# How to prepare for the final round interview?

Tags: interviewing

I have applied for a junior data analyst position. I passed three interviews, including technical, with the manager and the recruiter.

Now in the final round they gave me a small project and want me to try my best to solve it and prepare a report and a Powerpoint file for a 1-hour presentation.

I don't have experience with this interview format; how can I best prepare for it?

This is the project description:

> Perform a detailed analysis on the factors which impact sales of xxx. Based on the findings of your analysis make recommendation(s) to the business about changes that could be made in order to increase revenue from those products
>
> ...
>
> For the analysis you can use any software or programming language of your choosing. During the interview you will be asked to present two items:
>
> - The workings behind your analysis, containing a brief explanation of the steps you took (Notebook or Word Document)
> - A short PowerPoint slide deck (8 slides or less) that will summarise your key findings and recommendations to a non-technical audience.

Comment: There is no way to know, but since you got into the final round it looks good. Try your best

Comment: Did you get it then?

Comment: They sure do waste a lot of potential employees time nowadays. Three rounds a technical interview and a project. I cannot imagine an employer for which I would want to work so badly that I would do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made it to the last round of interviews - that's a big achievement in of itself. Normally at this stage there's likely only a handful of people left (perhaps just yourself) and so this is the time for you to shine.

Make sure you read and re-read the brief that they've given you. For every question that is 'asked' in the brief, make sure first and foremost you have answered that exact question.

Be clear in *how* you answered the question - to use a simple example, if the brief asks for a Gross Profit - make sure you have Gross Profit and make sure you have articulate how you've calculated it (Sum of all transactions).

Once you have addressed everything in the brief, perhaps include one or two complimentary metrics - e.g. they might want a break down of what is the most profitable item - so you answer that in terms of Gross profit (answering the question that is asked) but then supplementary to that answer, you include items that have a high profit margin (e.g. Item 1 has a gross profit of $10 - costing $20 to make and being sold for $30 - a 50% markup, but Item 2 costs $1 to make, but sells for $5 - $4 gross profit, but a 500% markup)

Then make sure you know your numbers and your analysis methods inside out and back to front - go in there and articulate why you are the best candidate for the job.

Comment: wow! thanks. good one. They also wanted me to have a powerpoint presentation in 8 slides max. I added the project above. anything else I should know? specifically the word file i dont know what to put and how to show?A

Comment: You work file should have all the details used to generate your PowerPoint slides.  For something like this I would start with an "Abstract" or "Executive Summary" that gives the salient point in a 1/2 page or so.  Then an "Introduction", a description of the analysis performed, how you did it, what you found.  All the gory details.  Finally end with your "Summary".

Comment: It seems that they want to assess your problem solving skills and then how you present and communicate.  This is a real-world example of something that you very likely will do repeatedly in your career.  So it's good.  Those silly online coding tests are useless.  Never in my career have I done anything even remotely resembling one of those.

Comment: @jwh20 - ditto; 30 years in my field I never once gained anything from those online tests & didn’t have the ability to Google for syntax or help understanding a conceptual programming problem

Comment: @jwh20 so do I have a chance? Are they going to ask hard questions? This is junior level!

Comment: This is a Junior level position. They're not expecting ground-breaking insights into the data; they want to see basic Excel skills (and any other tools which may be standard for the role), presented in a Word document with a PowerPoint presentation which backs up the Word document. Do your best.

Comment: @ PeteCon thanks. The question does not seem to be junior!

Comment: So junior level should not be so hard right?